# Most efficient way to handle xlsx / xls input in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have to write a spring batch program which should handle excel input.

Is there an itemreader present for excel files.

Special case: What if I am unsure about the input format of the file. It could be any of xlsx or xls and the program should be able to handle both.

Solution I have in my hand: Read excel using poi or jexcel and write into a dat file which could then be processed using FlatFileItemReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own ExcelFileItemReader implementing [ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream.html) interface and use poi/jexcel libraries there.

Don't forget to look at [FlatFileItemReader](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.java) source code.